# Can I serialize negative integer by NSJSONSerialization?

Tags: ios, nsnumber, nsjsonserialization

I can't serialize negative integer by NSJSONSerialization.

**Objective-C :**

```
NSMutableDictionary *sendData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: 
                          @480, @"width",
                          @800, @"height"
                          @-10, @"value1", 
                          @10, @"value2", nil];


NSError *error = nil;
NSData *dataJSon = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sendData options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"sendData\n %@ \n\n", [sendData description]);
```

**Log**

```
sendData{ 
           width = 480;      // int
           height = 800;     // int
           value1 = "-10";   // string. Not integer!!
           value2 = 10;      // int
          }
```

How can I serialize negative integer?

Comment: Nope, you can't!! NSMutableDictionary is key-value based data structure. TO serialise you can maintain extra array of keys based on sorted values..

Comment: you want to serialize the value = "-10"; to string or something correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, and everything's fine. That's just the dictionary -description being misleading.

```
NSMutableDictionary *sendData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:-10], @"value1",
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:10], @"value2", nil];


    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *dataJSon = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:sendData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"sendData\n %@ \n\n", [sendData objectForKey:@"value1"]);
```